# Mongo distinct sort query using PHP driver

Tags: php, mongodb

Having some trouble issuing a simple query from the PHP Mongo driver.
This is the shell query:

```
db.testing.distinct('summary.type').sort();
```

According to the documentation, I can do a `db->command` to use the distinct query. Here is what I've tried:

```
$all_types = $db->command(
      array(
             "distinct"      => "summary.type",
             "key"           => "summary.type"
      )
);

var_dump($all_types);
```

But rather than getting back the data I expect, I only get a cursor with indexes like `stats`, `nscanned` and `nscannedObjects`
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,
**ns**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commands don't return a MongoCursor object, but always just one document. Just like with `findOne()`. In this returned document, the `values` array element in the returned array contains an array of all your results:

```
<?php
$m = new Mongo; $c = $m->demo->pubs; $c->drop();

$c->insert( array( 'name' => 'Betsy Smith',   'city' => 'London' ) );
$c->insert( array( 'name' => 'London Tavern', 'city' => 'London' ) );
$c->insert( array( 'name' => 'Lammars',       'city' => 'Manchester' ) );
$c->insert( array( 'name' => 'Weatherspoons', 'city' => 'Coventry' ) );

$r = $m->demo->command( array(
    'distinct' => 'pubs',
    'key' => 'city',
    'query' => array( 'name' => array( '$ne' => 'Weatherspoons' ) )
) );
var_dump( $r['values'] );
?>
```

Which returns:

```
array(2) {
  [0] =>
  string(6) "London"
  [1] =>
  string(10) "Manchester"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The result you're looking for is actually in the `values` key of the command's response. If you look at the entire output of `var_dump()`, you'll see keys for `values`, `stats` (which you referred to), and `ok`.

On the JavaScript console, the collection's `distinct()` helper function actually handles the unwrapping for you, which you can see when viewing the source:

```
> db.testing.distinct
function (keyString, query) {
    var res = this._distinct(keyString, query);
    if (!res.ok) {
        throw "distinct failed: " + tojson(res);
    }
    return res.values;
}
```

Also, I believe you have an error in the command being issued through the PHP driver. The `distinct` option should refer to the collection name, and `key` should refer to the field name. See the [Distinct docs](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Aggregation#Aggregation-Distinct) for more information on that.